# Yii framework: showdialogbox (CJuiDialog)

Tags: php, widget, yii

I would like to open a dialogbox , but it should be like a part of my menu. I got a CMenu like this:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>"#", 'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;'),

                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                                array('label'=>'About Me', 'url'=>array('/site/index'), 
                                    'items'=>array(
                                             array('label'=>'CV', 'url'=>array('/site/cv')),
                                             array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')))),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),



                                array('label'=>'Register', 'url'=>array('/tblUsers/create'))

            ),
        )); ?>
```

as u can see i already tried to add it somehow to my menu but i have no idea what i am doing. I can open it outside like this :

```
echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
   'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;'));
```

So this is what i actually try to implement in the menu above, with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `linkOptions` or `itemOptions` for this purpose:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
  'items'=>array(
    array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>"#", 'linkOptions' => array(
       'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;'),
    )),
    /* other menu items */
  )
)); ?>
```

[Link to api docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#items-detail)

Comment: Ohh thank you a lot its working, didnt know about that option. A lot to learn. :)